# onreadystatechange triggers reload of page

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to learn some combined php, javascript, sql, html stuff...
I created something that works flawlessly on firefox (both WinXP and android version).
The desired action is that, whenever i click the button "process!", a php script takes the text in the "textarea", put each word into a database and spits back some html...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somestyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>

function ajaxUpdate()
{
    var currStr = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
    document.getElementById("textfield").value = currStr.trim();
    var response;
    try{
        var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(error){
        document.write(error);
    }
    httpReq.open("POST", "ajaxinput.php", true);
    httpReq.send(currStr);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(httpReq.readyState == 4){
            response = httpReq.responseText;
            document.getElementById("ajaxoutput").innerHTML = response;

        }
    }

}

function processText(){
    //document.write("in processURL");
    url = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    document.getElementById("m_block").innerHTML = document.getElementById("m_block").innerHTML + "<br/>text is being worked on by server..."

    var response;
    try{
        var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(error){
        document.write(error);
    }
    httpReq.open("POST", "textinput.php", true);
    httpReq.send(document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(httpReq.readyState == 4){
            response = httpReq.responseText;
            document.getElementById("m_block").innerHTML = response;
        }
    }

}

</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="l_block"></div>
    <div id="m_block">
    <form>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="42">Insert text here!</textarea> 
    <button onclick="processText()">process!</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="r1_block">css 2</div>
    <div id="r2_block">css 1</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The response from the php-script looks like this:

```
 search: <input type="text" id="textfield" onkeyup="ajaxUpdate()" />
 <div id="ajaxoutput"></div>
```

I call things "ajax", i have no idea whatsoever if this is what ajax is supposed to be. But i call it this because it is supposed to send off the string in `textfield` on each keyup event. Felt a bit ajax as far as i understand it.

Nevertheless, this works really well on firefox as i said, but nothing happens when i try it on other browsers. All that happens seems to be that the page reloads with an appended `?` to the URL in the address bar...

I could ask all my friends to just use firefox, but i am curious as to what is causing this. Where do i go wrong.

Thanks!

**EDIT!**
I did some digging in Chrome's debugger. Turns out the response gets back alright. When i set breakpoints i see that the div gets populated with the new content. However, the callback function gets called twice in a row. After it has finished i reverts back to the previous content, the server response is nowhere to be found anymore. What is happening?

Comment: Exactly which "*other browsers*" are you trying? What versions? [`string.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is a relatively new method and isn't available everywhere: [compatibility](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim). Also, check your browser's dev tools. Most have them built-in now and allow pausing when exceptions occur.

Comment: Sorry, ofcourse, IE8, Chome desktop winxp and android, Opera for Android, Firefox 19 for WinXP and the android version, HTC oneX browser, Iphone browser and Midori browser for Linux. Only the two Firefox versions did what i wanted...

Comment: Also, removing the `trim()` did nothing.

Comment: For both IE8 and Chrome, tap `F12` to open the dev tools. In IE, you can "[Start debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx)" under "Scripts." In Chrome, you can enable [pausing on all or uncaught exceptions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions) under "Sources" (button along the bottom). And, in Chrome (and later versions of IE), you can watch "Network" to inspect requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

I today faced exactly the same issue, might be useful for someone tomorrow.

In the form element, the input type was "submit" and form had onsubmit="func()". Like below:

```
<form id="x" name="x"  onsubmit="func()">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

For some reason I don't understand, in chrome the whole page is reloaded after returning from xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() with "?" in the end. Exactly like the OP posted.

I read somewhere to use type="button", then form element has to be updated to onclick="func()". Following code is working perfectly for me:

```
<form id="x" name="x"  onclick="func()">
    <input type="button" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

It would be great if someone can explain why it is happening that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jonathan said you did not mentioned which browser so its hard to give you concrete answer. Also your AJAX implementation seems incomplete please give this a try

```
//Put this on top before anything
if(!String.prototype.trim) 
{  
    String.prototype.trim = function () 
    {  
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');  
    };  
}
```

Also update your AJAX related code with this.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","textinput.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

You can also try using library like jQuery which will take care of most browser inconsistency.

Comment: why is the `.send()`commented out?

Comment: Updating as per your suggestions didn't help.

Comment: Send uses the sample data so I commented it out. Sorry I should have mentioned that before. Can you please update code with what you have tried or perhaps use Fiddle so that I can give you proper answer.